# Merge R data frames with differing lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

There are three data sets

**Parent Category:**

```
ID 
Ants
Cow
Dog
Hen
Tiger
```

**df1:**

```
ID     Number1
Ants    6
Dog     2
Hen     7
```

**df2:**

```
ID     Number2
Ants    5
Cow     7
Tiger   3
```

The final data (**df3**) should look like this:

```
ID      Number1  Number2
Ants       6        5
Cow        0        7
Dog        2        0
Hen        7        0
Tiger      0        3
```

Is there any direct way to achieve this in R. I can do it in a manual way where I try to find out the missing values and then input it in each row and assign it to 0 and then arrange it in ascending order. Lastly I will merge the two data frames into one. But can we make a function that can do all this for us, with even more than two datasets.

I found a solution,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568788/merge-many-r-data-frames-by-row-names-with-differing-lengths)

but this is taking to much of time to run and showing the error
Error: cannot allocate a vector of size 46.0 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can put all dataframes into a list and use `Reduce` and `merge` from base R:

```
df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='ID', all.x=TRUE), list(parent, df1, df2))
df[is.na(df)] <- 0 

     ID Number1 Number2
1  Ants       6       5
2   Cow       0       7
3   Dog       2       0
4   Hen       7       0
5 Tiger       0       3
```

Or we can use `join_all` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
join_all(list(parent, df1, df2), by='ID', type='left') %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Or with `purrr::reduce`:

```
library(tidyverse)

reduce(list(parent, df1, df2), left_join, by = 'ID') %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))
```

**Data**

```
parent <- structure(list(ID = c("Ants", "Cow", "Dog", "Hen", "Tiger")), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("Ants", "Dog", "Hen"), 
                      Number1 = c(6L, 2L, 7L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("Ants", "Cow", "Tiger"), 
                      Number2 = c(5L, 7L, 3L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `full_join` from `dplyr` :

```
full_join(df1, df2, "ID") %>% replace_NA(0)
```

For your data :

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("Ants", "Dog", "Hen"), Number1 = c(6,2,7))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("Ants", "Cow", "Tiger"), Number2 = c(5,7,3))

full_join(df1, df2, "ID") %>% replace_NA(0) %>% arrange(ID)
```

Comment: this works, but only for two data frames, thanks a lot though